# IP subnet /17 for latter range (x.x.128.0 - x.x.255.255)

Tags: subnet

[This site](https://www.dan.me.uk/ipsubnets) shows `115.93.0.0/17` has the range of `115.93.0.0 - 115.93.127.255`

I'd like to setup firewall range of `115.93.128.0 - 115.93.255.255`.
how can I say it with subnet? my firewall console only accepts x.x.x.x/subnet field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP address slash notation and subnet masks and be confusing, but [thanks to online calculators like this](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=115.93.128.0&mask1=17&mask2=255.255.128.0), you can easily experiment. This should work:

```
115.93.128.0/17
```

Note the range would be from `115.93.128.1` to `115.93.255.254` since there is no `0` network address and `115.93.255.255` is reserved for the broadcast address. The netmask would be `255.255.128.0`. But this is close enough I would hope.